# Interface and overloading

Tags: c#

I have a question about best practice.

I have an interface used for sending messages. First I was set only to sms text and now I have decided to also implement emails however I still need to use only one interface. Now my interface contains two methods and I am taking as parameter Message which is fine for the sms however not ok for the email because my email needs to have different properties such as subject.

Can you please advise me how to use only one interface or what should I change?

```
public interface IMessageSender
{
    Task<MessageResult> SendAsync(Message message);

    MessageResult Send(Message message);
}

public class Message
{
    public string Sender { get; set; }

    public string Reciever { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class EmailMessage : Message
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You could add the `Subject` property to `Message`.  That wouldn't change the interface.  Then in the SMS implementation if there's a `Subject` value provided make it the first line of the message, separated from the `Body` by a carriage return or something.

Comment: So, you want to create an interface for handling two things that are conceptually distinct. A "Message" either has a subject or it does not. Otherwise, create an `IMessage` interface with something like a `.Send()` method that allows the message to write itself to your output stream (or whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, the base `Message` type includes a virtual method named `Send()`. You then have types for `SMSMessage` and `EMailMessage` which override the `Send()` method so polymorphism can decide which one to call.

Newer paradigms don't like this as much, because it can be harder to unit test. You can test the individual `Send()` methods, but not that the right one will be called in the moment. So we have things like Inversion of Control, stubbing/mocking, etc, which generally want to you write and implement extra interfaces like `IMessageSender`, to add a layer of abstraction where you can verify this happens correctly.

This gives us a new problem: how to know the correct `MessageSender` is used? And so now we add another pattern: `MessageSenderFactory()`, which accepts a `Message` and returns an instance of the correct sender type.

And just like that you're writing Java.

---

The point is to look carefully at just how far down this rabbit hole you want to go. **Right now, this situation can be solved with a simple `if()` conditional for what kind of message you want to send**, but patterns from various programming disciplines will ask you to add several layers on top of this. *And they're not wrong.* The additional layers and conventions do add meaningful value in terms of testing, flexibility, adaptability, reliability, and recognizable patterns. Much of the time they are the way to go. But they also add complexity, code, and cognitive load to your software. So some awareness of this is valuable, too.

Comment: well my method send is in the interface and i have tried to make it abstract but then i have to implement body which is very different for the provider of sms and of email

Comment: So  you think i should implement another interface for email? Sorry i am not getting it

Comment: Well, at some point you have to implement sending an SMS and sending an email. There's no way around that.

Comment: I'm saying you should look carefully at just how far down this rabbit hole you want to go. **Right now, this situation can be solved with a simple `if()` conditional.** But various programming disciplines can ask you to add layer after layer on top of this. And they're _not wrong_. The extra layers and patterns do add value in terms of testing, flexibility, adaptability, reliability, and recognizable patterns. But they also add complexity, code, and cognitive load to your software. So some awareness of this is valuable, too.

Comment: Oh, Java... my day just got worse.

Comment: Promoting the longer comment into the answer.